# git: External Diff Tool for Interactive Mode

Tags: git, terminal, git-diff

I know there is a way to set different diff and merge tools, but is there also a possibility to use an external tool for the interactive mode? When I do:

```
git add -p <file>
```

the internal git diff is being used I suppose. I'd like to use a different tool (e.g. [cdif](https://github.com/kaz-utashiro/cdif)).

I've already googled around and tried various config options changing the diff and merge tool, but it seems they're not used during an interactive session.